# Output Sass <----> CSS?

Tags: css, sass, preprocessor

I'm looking to setup a scenario where a sass file outputs css and that css file outputs back to the sass file. So, if I were to code in the css file it would update the sass file, and if I were to code in the sass file it would update the css file.

Basically, something like `--watch input.sass output.css` and `--watch output.css input.sass` combined.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: one SASS file can generate only *one* CSS file but one CSS file can be generated by *many* SASS files. How you would define a CSS to SASS conversion? (also note that a CSS file is a particular SASS file)

Comment: I don't need Sass to generate more than one CSS file. I need the Sass file to generate a single CSS file that also generates back to Sass on change. Only two files.

Comment: *I don't need Sass to generate more than one CSS file* --> it cannot generate more than one file, it can generate only one. The issue is the other direction: one CSS syntax can be generated by different SASS codes so how you would define a CSS to SASS conversion?

Comment: Okay I see your point. You're talking about a situation for example in which partials are used, and asking how the CSS will generate back to the partials?

Comment: partials, variables, mixins, modules, nesting, etc etc .. you have nothing about this at CSS level so converting CSS to SASS has no meaning since you can create an infinite number of SASS file that gives the same output